# Error : TF400534 : Package (tfs_sharePointInstaller) caching failed with the following status : 0x80096010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, tfs

I am getting this error

"Error : TF400534 : Package (tfs_sharePointInstaller) caching failed with the following status : 0x80096010."

Answer (score 2):

There's only one cause for this. The setup cache is corrupted.
This can happen

1. When actually the setup is corrupted.
2. When the setup copies itself to the hard disk, the part which it was copied to in the hard  disk is corrupted.
3. There is not enough disk space in your system drive for the setup to copy itself to.